# How to make use of the Cython modules in Apache Beam?

Tags: apache-beam

Beam has support for Cython, but there are no instructions how to make use of it in an application (https://beam.apache.org/get-started/quickstart-py/). Are there any extra dependencies that need to be installed?

Comment: I should also mention that in my application I'm using the Python SDK with the Flink runner, so how the SDK workers are deployed and run may be relevant. In this case we are not using the Docker containers, but run the workers as direct processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that the Python SDK has some Cython optimizations.

To ensure that these are available to you when you install Beam, make sure to have Cython installed in your environment. If you have Cython installed, Beam will go ahead and compile its modules when possible.

In short, before running `pip install apache-beam`, you'd want to run `pip install Cython` first.

---

To add some more detail, check out [Beam's `setup.py`](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/7a5252e90faab1f6f7299f8f26b2461e50b2742b/sdks/python/setup.py#L79-L102). When Beam is installed, it will check for a Cython installation, and if it does find one, it will attempt to cythonize its modules.

Comment: Note for building the package from source: Cython has to be installed in both the build and runtime environment. The Apache Beam package has the Cython support.